# Using melt function: Variable and Value

Tags: r, melt

I used the `melt` function to combine some variable under a single column:

```
melt(p,id= c("year","month","carrier","carrier_name","airport","airport_name","arr_cancelled","arr_diverted","arr_delay"))
```

The melted data looks fine with all identifiers in place. The problem is the melted data is shown under 2 columns `Variable` and `Value`. I want to plot a graph using the data under `Variable` but it is throwing the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found.
```

Do I have to map the melted data under `Variable` and `Value` to something so as to make it useful. How can I use the melted data?

Comment: If using non-base functions, always report packages those functions come from. Also please read about how to provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `variable` vs `Variable` may be

Comment: I have used the Reshape package

Comment: what is your `p` object. Please include `dput(p)` in your original post.

Comment: `reshape` or `reshape2`